# Copying File From One User To Another

Tags: linux, file-permissions, postgresql

So I have this file stored in my account. It's postgres dump. To be able to use postgres it seems that I have to execute the following command.

```
sudo su - postgres
```

Once I do this I am now working as the `postgres` user. What I need to be able to do is use the dump file (tied to my account `ahcarpenter`) as the `postgres` user. Any ideas as to how to go about this?

Or really simply just access the file located within my other account's directory within the `postgres` user's directory.

Answer (score 1):

If the file does not contain sensitive information, simply flag it as readable by anyone:

```
chmod o+r yourdumpfile
```

And then use it from the `postgres` user.

If it does contain sensitive information, then you should copy it to the postgres users's home directory, and `chown` it to them:

```
chown postgres /path/to/postgres/home/yourdumpfile
```